# Oracle Forms Post-Query FRM-40735 and ORA-01422

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, eventtrigger, ora-01422

I want to display the item from different table, I am using `POST-QUERY` trigger
:

```
SELECT Stock_code
  INTO :exchange.stockcode
  FROM Exchange_Stock
 WHERE Exchange_code = :exchange.Exchange_code;
```

it come up with `FRM-40735` and `ORA-01422`
but it display some of the record (not all),
I have no idea what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the `POST-QUERY` trigger fires just after the fields of table-based block with multiple records are populated. Obviously `Exchange_code` values are not unique throughout the table data, whereas a `SELECT .. INTO .. FROM ...` clause only can bring one row record.

So, you can try to filter out the results so as to get single rows for each parameter fields combinations such as `:exchange.Exchange_code` & `:exchange.code_order` instead of only `:exchange.Exchange_code` field within the `WHERE` condition :

```
SELECT Stock_code
  INTO :exchange.stockcode
  FROM Exchange_Stock
 WHERE Exchange_code = :exchange.Exchange_code
   AND code_order = :exchange.code_order;
```

where important thing is to get single row from the query matching for each record in the data block. You can still add more condition to the query if this condition is not provided yet.